# vue3 + typescript: TS2345: Argument of type 'Router' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin_2'

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In our yarn multi workspace project we get a very strange typescript build exception with the latest version of vue:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Router' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin_2'.
  Type 'Router' is not assignable to type '{ install: PluginInstallFunction; }'.
    Types of property 'install' are incompatible.
      Type '(app: App<any>) => void' is not assignable to type 'PluginInstallFunction'.
        Types of parameters 'app' and 'app' are incompatible.
          Type 'import("/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").App<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core").App<any>'.
```

To me it does look, like they are identicall...

The relevant parts of the package.json:

```json
{
   "dependencies": {
     "vue": "^3.2.31",
     "vue-router": "4.0.12",
     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
     "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
     "typescript": "~4.1.5"
   }
}
```

Anybody had this before and knows maybe how to fix it without going through the lengthy process of opening vue core tickets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll it looks like an oddity of yarn...

We upgraded now all dependencies of vue to `"vue": "^3.2.29"` and the error is gone.

Comment: I was on vue 3.2.45, upgraded to 3.2.47 and it worked as well. 
Seems like a yarn oddity indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error appeared when installing Element plus UI. And I decided to set the type `"types": ["element-plus/global"]` in tsconfig.json

Update:
It is just as easy to solve a problem of the specified type `as any`. I do not know how correct this is, but the typescript does not always show an error. For example:
`createApp(App).use(i18n as any).use(ElementPlus).use(router as any).use(createPinia() as any).mount('#app')`

Comment: I would not put too much trust in "as any", perhaps as a temorary solution tho

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered different versions of Vue between the app and the plugin.

The app installed `vue@3.4.15`, and the plugin installed `vue@3.4.21`, and with another plugin `vue@3.3.4`.